# Google Script for Conditional Email

Tags: google-apps-script

I am trying to write a script which sends email to different addresses based on the module i.e air, water..

```
function emailspecialist() {
    var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById("15Om5F29GIlu77rQa4K26QKY_4qeZaF-6F5LRqAXqkFI");
    var startRow = 2;
    var numRows = 1000;
    var dataRange = sheet.getRange("A1:G1000")
    var data = dataRange.getValues();
    for (var i = 0; i < data.length; ++i) {
        var row = data[i];
        var module = row[4]
        if(module=="Air Quality"){
            var email="gooco.pm@energy.com.ph"+","+"flores.ef@energy.com.ph"+","+"rvjpascual@energy.com.ph";}
        else if(module=="Water Quality"){
            var email="cedino.lar@energy.com.ph"+","+"flores.ef@energy.com.ph"+","+"rvjpascual@energy.com.ph";}
        else if(module=="Chemicals Management"){
            var email="santiago.ce@energy.com.ph"+","+"flores.ef@energy.com.ph"+","+"rvjpascual@energy.com.ph";}
        else if(module=="Wastes Management"){
            var email="santiago.ce@energy.com.ph"+","+"flores.ef@energy.com.ph"+","+"rvjpascual@energy.com.ph";}
        else if(module=="EIA"){
            var email="walican.nsw@energy.com.ph"+","+"flores.ef@energy.com.ph"+","+"rvjpascual@energy.com.ph";}
        else if(module=="Others"){
            var email="flores.ef@energy.com.ph"+","+"rvjpascual@energy.com.ph";
        }
    var requester=row[2];
    var group=row[3];
    var description=row[5];
    var completion=row[6];
    MailApp.sendEmail(email, requester, description);
   }}
```

Here's what I have done so far..

Hope someone can help me. Thanks in advance

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! I recommend you [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour).

Answer (score 0):

If this script is original, the number of mails which will send is "data.length" defined by "A1:G1000". If you want to send email using the value of "module", "MailApp.sendEmail()" should put into "if". So how about this script?

```
function emailspecialist() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById("15Om5F29GIlu77rQa4K26QKY_4qeZaF-6F5LRqAXqkFI");
  var startRow = 2;
  var numRows = 1000;
  var dataRange = sheet.getRange("A1:G1000")
  var data = dataRange.getValues();
  for (var i = 0; i < data.length; ++i) {
    if(module=="Air Quality"){
      var email="gooco.pm@energy.com.ph"+","+"flores.ef@energy.com.ph"+","+"rvjpascual@energy.com.ph";}
    else if(module=="Water Quality"){
      var email="cedino.lar@energy.com.ph"+","+"flores.ef@energy.com.ph"+","+"rvjpascual@energy.com.ph";}
    else if(module=="Chemicals Management"){
      var email="santiago.ce@energy.com.ph"+","+"flores.ef@energy.com.ph"+","+"rvjpascual@energy.com.ph";}
    else if(module=="Wastes Management"){
      var email="santiago.ce@energy.com.ph"+","+"flores.ef@energy.com.ph"+","+"rvjpascual@energy.com.ph";}
    else if(module=="EIA"){
      var email="walican.nsw@energy.com.ph"+","+"flores.ef@energy.com.ph"+","+"rvjpascual@energy.com.ph";}
    else if(module=="Others"){
      var email="flores.ef@energy.com.ph"+","+"rvjpascual@energy.com.ph";}
    else {
      var email = "";
    }
    if (email.length > 0) {
      var row         = data[i];
      var requester   = row[2];
      var group       = row[3];
      var module      = row[4];
      var description = row[5];
      var completion  = row[6];
      MailApp.sendEmail(email, requester, description);    
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much.  This is really helpful. It solved the problem straight away. I inserted var module inside the loop so it will be identified by the conditions.

Comment: By the way, how can I prevent the whole thing for repeating all entries?

Comment: What are all entries?

Comment: I posted a revised version of the script you gave me. I am trying to include a emailSent function

Comment: Is that new question?

Answer (score -1):

I am trying to put in an emailSent function so that entries already emailed will not be repeated. Here's my edited version which doesnt work at the meantime.

```
 function emailspecialist() {
 var sheet =  SpreadsheetApp.openById("16OxeGOCb7wur4k0qc0dMWbUt_tSvf4elfefZIpqWBSc");
 var startRow = 2;
 var numRows = 1000;
 var dataRange = sheet.getRange("A1:G1000")
 var data = dataRange.getValues();
 var emailSent = "Email Sent";
 for (var i = 0; i < data.length; ++i) {
  var module = data[i][4];
  if(module=="Air Quality"){
  var email="gooco.pm@energy.com.ph";}
  else if(module=="Water Quality"){
     var email="cedino.lar@energy.com.ph"+","+"flores.ef@energy.com.ph"+","+"rvjpascual@energy.com.ph";}
   else if(module=="Chemicals Management"){
     var email="santiago.ce@energy.com.ph"+","+"flores.ef@energy.com.ph"+","+"rvjpascual@energy.com.ph";}
   else if(module=="Wastes Management"){
     var email="santiago.ce@energy.com.ph"+","+"flores.ef@energy.com.ph"+","+"rvjpascual@energy.com.ph";}
   else if(module=="EIA"){
     var email="walican.ns@energy.com.ph"+","+"flores.ef@energy.com.ph"+","+"rvjpascual@energy.com.ph";}
   else if(module=="Others"){
     var email="flores.ef@energy.com.ph"+","+"rvjpascual@energy.com.ph";}
   else {
    var email = "";
}
  if (email.length > 0) {
  var row         = data[i];
  var requester   = row[2];
  var group       = row[3];
  var description = row[5];
  var completion  = row[6];
  var isEmailSent = row[7];
  if (isEmailSent != emailSent) {
  MailApp.sendEmail(email, requester, description);
  sheet.getRange(startRow + i, 7).setValue(emailSent);  
  }}
 }
}
```

Comment: You should put this in the question instead of an answer as this does not solve the problem as per your own words. Please be more specific what doesn't work in this particular format. So far, for each row you should be emailing once, however if there are several entries that are the same it will trigger twice, unless you only allow sending an email once. In that case you can simply use a variable to count how many times each address was emailed.